# How to identify soap Request is SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2

Tags: java, soap, soap1.2

In java, How do I check if the version of SOAP Request XML is SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2.

Comment: Do you have the WSDL file with you?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do this.Think following is your SOAP message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    .........
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    ....
</soapenv:Body>
```

You can distinguish these two using soapenv property.

SOAP 1.1 : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

SOAP 1.2 : http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope

So you will find that the above soap message is related to SOAP 1.1. Think this will be helpful to you.

for more details see : [WSO2 library artical](http://wso2.com/library/articles/differentiating-between-soap-versions-looking-soap-message/) on this